# Remove empty documents from DocumentTermMatrix in R topicmodels?

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling, topicmodels

I am doing topic modelling using the topicmodels package in R. I am creating a Corpus object, doing some basic preprocessing, and then creating a DocumentTermMatrix:

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(vec), readerControl=list(language="en")) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
...snip removing several custom lists of stopwords...
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control=list(minDocFreq=2, minWordLength=2))
```

And then performing LDA:

```
LDA(dtm, 30)
```

This final call to LDA() returns the error

```
  "Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry".
```

I assume this means that there is at least one document that has no terms in it after preprocessing. Is there an easy way to remove documents that contain no terms from a DocumentTermMatrix?

I looked in the documentation for the topicmodels package and found the function removeSparseTerms, which removes terms that do not appear in any document, but there is no analogue for removing documents.

Comment: When you do inspect(corpus) , do you see some emty document? and LDA is in which package?

Comment: I am using the function LDA from the topicmodels package. I have about 51,000 documents so I can't really manually check with inspect. Also, it's possible that some terms are getting removed by the minDocFreq=2, minWordLength=2 parameters, so what I really want to check is the DocumentTermMatrix. Is there another way of finding empty documents?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
"Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry"
```

The error means that sparse matrix contain a row without entries(words). one Idea is to compute the sum of words by row

```
rowTotals <- apply(dtm , 1, sum) #Find the sum of words in each Document
dtm.new   <- dtm[rowTotals> 0, ]           #remove all docs without words
```

Comment: This works just fine. I didn't realize a DocumentTermMatrix could be indexed like that. Thanks!

Comment: @BillM it is a matrix, special yes (sparse), but still a matrix.

Comment: This solution has one potential issue: the resulting matrix without zero-words documents will not correspond anymore to the original corpus, i.e., it will have a smaller number of rows. Therefore it will not be possible to use the result of LDA to categorize the corpus (for example by assigning the best cluster to each document). Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I receive this error: `rror in vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) : vector size cannot be NA
In addition: Warning message:
In nr * nc : NAs produced by integer overflow`

Comment: In one line, without using an apply: `dtm[rowSums(dtm)>0,]`

Answer (score 28):

agstudy's answer works great, but using it on a slow computer proved mildly problematic.

```
tic()
row_total = apply(dtm, 1, sum)
dtm.new = dtm[row_total>0,]
toc()
4.859 sec elapsed
```

(this was done with a 4000x15000 dtm)

The bottleneck appears to be applying `sum()` to a sparse matrix.

A document-term-matrix created by the `tm` package contains the names i and j , which are indices for where entries are in the sparse matrix. If `dtm$i` does not contain a particular row index `p`, then row `p` is empty.

```
tic()
ui = unique(dtm$i)
dtm.new = dtm[ui,]
toc()
0.121 sec elapsed
```

`ui` contains all the non-zero indices, and since `dtm$i` is already ordered, `dtm.new` will be in the same order as `dtm`. The performance gain may not matter for smaller document term matrices, but may become significant with larger matrices.

Comment: This solution is better than the previous one in terms of memory required!

Answer (score 13):

This is just to elaborate on the answer given by agstudy.

Instead of removing the empty rows from the dtm matrix, we can identify the documents in our corpus that have zero length and remove the documents directly from the corpus, before performing a second dtm with only non empty documents.

This is useful to keep a 1:1 correspondence between the dtm and the corpus.

`empty.rows <- dtm[rowTotals == 0, ]$dimnames[1][[1]]
corpus <- corpus[-as.numeric(empty.rows)]`

Comment: For me second line of the code threw this error Error in `[.VCorpus`(corpus, 1, 1) : unused argument (1). I modified it to          corpus <- corpus[-as.numeric(empty.rows)]

Comment: A corpus is a list so you cannot use 2D selection. You simply want `corpus[-as.numeric(empty.rows)]` (i.e. one dimension).

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the sparse terms from the DTM and all will work well.

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, sparse=TRUE)
```

Comment: dtm<-removeSparseTerms(dtm, sparse=0.98)

Answer (score 0):

Just small addendum to the answer of Dario Lacan:

```
empty.rows <- dtm[rowTotals == 0, ]$dimnames[1][[1]]
```

will collect record's `id`, rather than order numbers. Try this:

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)
dtm[1, ]$dimnames[1][[1]] # return "127", not "1"
```

If you construct your own corpus with consecutive numbering, after data cleaning some documents can be removed and numbering also will be broken. So, it's better to use `id` directly:

```
corpus <- tm_filter(
  corpus,
  FUN = function(doc) !is.element(meta(doc)$id, empty.rows))
  # !( meta(doc)$id %in% emptyRows )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a column in a data frame `lt$title` which contained strings. I had no "empty" rows in this column, but still got the error:

> Error in LDA(dtm, k = 20, control = list(seed = 813)) :    Each row of
>   the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry

Some of the solutions above did not work for me, since I needed to join the vector of predicted topics to my original data frame. So removing non-zero entries from the document term matrix was no option.

The problem was, that some (very short) strings in `lt$title` contained special characters which could not be processed by `Corpus()` and/or `DocumentTermMatrix()`.

My solution was to remove "short" strings (one or two words max.) which do not carry much information anyway.

```
# Clean up text data
lt$test=nchar(lt$title)
lt = lt[!lt$test<10,]
lt$test<-NULL

# Topic modeling
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(lt$title))
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
tm = LDA(dtm, k = 20, control = list(seed = 813))

# Add "topics" to original DF
lt$topic = topics(tm)
```